# ember-cli Unclosed element `d.y` causing ember app to crash

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js, ember-cli

I have the following file `bubbles.hbs` in a ember-cli app with the following code, and I am getting the following error, `Unclosed element d.y (on line 56).`  I tried googling the problem, but could not find a solution.

**UPDATE**

Here is a fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/395jthv9/1/ of the code below, and appears to be working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// #5b342f
var beerBackground = d3.select("body").transition()
   .duration(2000)
   // carter wilson color = FFE152
   .style("background-color","#f5d037");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

w = window.innerWidth,
h = window.innerHeight;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(d3.range(70).map(function(datum,interval) {
          return {
            x: interval*20,
            y: 0,
            // stroke-width="1",
            dx: 5,
            dy: -3 * (Math.random()+1),
            mu: Math.random()*2
          };
        }))
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .attr("fill","#FFEFA0") // fill
        .attr("stroke","white") // stroke
       .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        // .attr("opacity",".0.2")
        .style("stroke-opacity", "1.0")
        .style("fill-opacity", ".5");

    var text = svg.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 20);

    var start = Date.now(),
        frames = 0;

    d3.timer(function() 
    {

  // Update the circle positions.
  circle
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        d.x += Math.random()*3*Math.sin(Math.random()*3*d.x + Math.random()*10); if (d.x > w) d.x -= w; else if (d.x < 0) d.x += w; return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        d.y += d.dy ; 
        if (d.y > h) {
          d.y -= h; 
        }
        // And the below line is giving me an error.
        else if (d.y < 0) {
         d.y += h; 
        }
          return d.y; 
      })
      .attr("r",function(d) {
        return (d.y < 100) ? d3.select(this).attr("r") : d.mu*500/d.y;
      }); --}}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put your JavaScript code in `.hbs` file using `<script>` tag. Move this code to JavaScript file instead.

So, move that code from `bubbles.hbs` to `bubbles.js`. You could for example execute that logic in `didInsertElement` hook if it's component, or after `init` event.

Comment: could provide the exact syntax required to load to the `bubbles.js` from the `vendor` dir?